# Out of memory error when joining a 140 million record CRM - using DuckDB and R

Tags: r, dplyr, out-of-memory, parquet, duckdb

I did not find an exact solution to my problem and had to collect information from different sources to get at a working solution. I am documenting (by answering) it here for reference.

**Problem statement**

I had two tables to join in R:

- tbl_1 (parquet): ~50k rows (20 columns)
- crm (parquet): ~140 million rows (62 columns)

The following code was taking more than 1 minute and often would throw "out of memory" error:

```
library(arrow)
library(here)
library(DBI)
library(dplyr)
library(duckdb)

PATH_TABLE_1 <- here("/home/data/tbl_1")
PATH_CRM <- here("/home/data/crm")

ds_tbl_1 <-
  open_dataset(PATH_TABLE_1, format = "parquet", partitioning="hive", hive_style = FALSE) |> 
  to_duckdb(con)

ds_crm <-
  open_dataset(PATH_CRM, format = "parquet", partitioning="hive", hive_style = FALSE) |> 
  to_duckdb(con)

ds_tbl_1 |> 
  head(10) |>
  left_join(
    ds_crm,
    join_by(phone_number == phone_number)
  )

DBI::dbDisconnect(con)
```

Notice, I was using only 10 records from tbl_1 (head) for testing. The CRM join was 1-1 so the result should be only 10 records.

Actual error:

```
Error in `collect()`:
! Failed to collect lazy table.
Caused by error:
! rapi_execute: Failed to run query
Error: Out of Memory Error: could not allocate block of size 262KB (215.8GB/215.8GB used)
Database is launched in in-memory mode and no temporary directory is specified.
Unused blocks cannot be offloaded to disk.

Launch the database with a persistent storage back-end
Or set PRAGMA temp_directory='/path/to/tmp.tmp'
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I didn't try setting the temp_directory as the time it took for joining 10 records was too long. In addition, I was not sure how to elegantly write the result to a parquet through streaming.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to use a persistent `DuckDB` file:

```
library(arrow)
library(here)
library(DBI)
library(dplyr)
library(duckdb)
library(glue)

PATH_TABLE_1 <- here("/home/data/tbl_1")
PATH_CRM <- here("/home/data/crm")
PATH_DUCKDB <- here("/home/data")

con <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb(), dbdir = here(PATH_DUCKDB, "temp_db.duckdb")) #, read_only = TRUE)

DBI::dbSendQuery(
  con,
  glue::glue(
    "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_1;
     CREATE TABLE tbl_1 AS
     SELECT * FROM read_parquet('{here(PATH_TABLE_1, '*/*.parquet')}')
    "
  )
)

DBI::dbSendQuery(
  con,
  glue::glue(
    "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS crm;
     CREATE TABLE crm AS
     SELECT * FROM read_parquet('{here(PATH_CRM, '*/*/*.parquet')}')"
  )
)

ds_tbl_1 <- tbl(con, "tbl_1")
ds_crm <- tbl(con, "crm")

ds_tbl_1 |> 
  left_join(
    ds_crm,
    join_by(phone_number == phone_number)
  ) |> 
  compute(name = "tbl_joined", temporary = FALSE)

tbl(con, "tbl_joined") |> 
  head()
```

Individual execution times for me were:

- tbl_1 creation: 2 minutes (*/*.parquet is due to partitioning on one key)
- crm creation: 8 minutes (*/*/*.parquet is due to partitioning on two keys)
- tbl_joined: 2 minutes

I was able to perform the needed analysis on tbl_joined.

Note: for my use case, the crm changes monthly so the 8 minute write does not bother me.

Comment: We connect to a remote SQL server to retrieve data and push the analyzed results. This repository serves R, Tableau and other front-ends that require this data. This is not a huge data, so wondering if I can replace it with duckDB. Can I host the duckDb data on a HPC, and allow users to connect via credentials like we do with SQL server?

Comment: From what you mentioned, I don't think vanilla duckDB is the right solution as you imply that read/write will be involved from multiple users. More information: https://duckdb.org/docs/connect/concurrency#handling-concurrency

Comment: if not multiple users, can I setup duck db on a storage system ( network drive or a remote storage like AWS or other server), then access it from a shiny app. We work with patient data, we are allowed to store them only on a network drive and behind Firewall or secured storage, but the problem is connecting to the data in a shiny app. Wondering if we can push that data to duck db which is also on shared drive,  and secure access it with a password or token